# I need to paint stained wood trim

Tags: trim, baseboard, spraypainting

The wood is newly stained, no varnish or shellac.  Do I need to do anything before I paint, or can I just go with primer?  I am spraying the wood white.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the stain is good and dry, and you'll be good to go.